# Task.ContinueWith from calling thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to execute the Func in ContinueWith from the thread that created the task (which is not GUI thread). I Tried this code:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

var scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
})
.ContinueWith(
    _ => Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId),
    // Specify where to execute the continuation
    scheduler
);

t.Wait();
```

But caller thread and .ContinueWith thread differs. Any idea why?
I get the following result:

> 1 3 3

Looks like passing the scheduler causes ContinueWith to execute from the thread that is executing the actual Task, where I want it to be executed from the thread, which created the Task, in this case 1.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: If you had a current synchronization context, this code would deadlock at `t.Wait();`, because the waiting won't process posted tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`:

```
ContinueWith(() => { ... }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

`ExecuteSynchronously` tells it to **try** and run the continuation on whatever thread was last executing the antecedent task. And in the case of a continuation executing after a `Task.Factory.StartNew` call, that thread would be a thread pool thread.

But you have to **note** that this is merely a hint and the framework won't always honor your request. So you shouldn't structure your code so that running on the same thread becomes a necessity.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I need to execute it asynchronously. And I don't have many choices, I'm maintening some legacy code :(

Comment: @Davita see the edit. `ExecuteSynchronously` doesn't mean it's running synchronously.

Comment: As I said, it's merely a hint, and since you're explicitly giving it a scheduler then that scheduler decides what thread gets to execute it. I believe what you want can't be done when you provider a scheduler.

Comment: I missed that you're using the scheduler only in the continuation. Is there a reason you're providing that scheduler in the first place (there are no sync contexts right)?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to schedule the continuation on the same thread as the antecedent task, he wants it to execute from the thread which created that said task.

Comment: Yeah I kind of understood that later on, but the answer has been accepted so I'm confused. @Davita did you get what you wanted? You can't use `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` if you're not in an environment that has one (WPF, winforms, asp.net ...). It will return null which will have no effect at all.

Comment: Hi, I guess it's not possible to achieve what i want, so I will go the other way...

Answer (score 3):

**SynchronizationContext** class uses ThreadPool.
If you need single thread synchronization context then you should use **DispatcherSynchronizationContext**, **WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext** or write your own synchronization context that will work according to your needs.